# How to have JFrame store the data and not refresh?

Tags: java, jframe

how do you store information in a jframe even after it is closed to open a separate jframe so that when the first jframe is reopened, the same information is still listed?

So basically i have a jFrame with a search button and profile button. the view profile button takes you to a different Jframe where all your "search history" is stored. However everytime you go back to the main page and open the profile again the profile refreshes and starts with nothing again. I want the button to open the exact same window again and not a new window of the GUI. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, the thing you need is `secondFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);`

However, having 2 JFrames is not recommended. You can use a JDialog instead for your "second frame".

Also if you initialize it in your button's action listener is not going to work since everytime the button is clicked, it will create a new Dialog. So you must initialize it before. Take a look at this example:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    private JDialog secondFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        initializeSecondFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Show \"Second Frame\".");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            secondFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
        getContentPane().add(button);
        setSize(300, 300);
    }

    private void initializeSecondFrame() {
        secondFrame = new JDialog(this);
        // When "X" button is presed, dialog does nothing.
        secondFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        secondFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        secondFrame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        secondFrame.setSize(300, 300);
    }
}
```

The only thing that the button does, it to make the dialog (which is initiated already) visible. Now if you edit the TextField in the dialog a.k.a the secondFrame, and close it, then press the button again, the textfield will have its text.